Is there any legal basis for a municipality paying the cost of repairing something that is (unjustifiably) classed by by-law as homeowner's property?
I live in a small municipality, and I pay property taxes. Today I found out that there is a blockage in the connection between my house and the wastewater main just at the point where the two pipes intersect, causing a major wastewater backup in my house. This point is directly underground of a main public road that is owned by the municipality. The only way to fix it is for the municipality themselves to drill into the main road.
On the "Sewage By-law" enacted several years ago by the council of the municipality, there is a lemma that reads:

All costs and expenses incident to the installation and connection of the building sanitary sewer and/or building storm sewer to the sewerage system and/or storm sewer system shall be borne by the Owner.

Reading this, it seems like the responsibility is entirely mine. However, this law does not seem to address the issue I face; namely, that the issue is not anywhere within my connecting sewer, but rather the sewer main, corresponding to a city road, which cannot be altered legally or practically by any party other than the municipality. They have not conducted a thorough investigation into the matter yet, but judging by several cracks and unevenness in the road at the point where the blockage occurs, it seems to be due to a fault in the pavement or construction of this road and perhaps the pipes under it. It is merely a coincidence that my house is the only one affected by this fault, and I am not at all accountable for the blockage that is faced at this sewer main.
Is there a legal way to get the municipality to pay for all expenses related to this issue, due to the fact that they are liable for the damage sustained? Or does the bylaw I quoted protect them entirely?

As I read the quote, your responsibility is for costs incident to "installation and connection" not maintenance.  Once connected it would seem that the city would have responsibility to maintain lines that are outside of your property lines.  Have you brought this up with the city?

That’s pretty typical
The utility (the small municipality in your case), owns the sewer, you, the property owner owns the sanitary drainage that connects to it. If the blockage is in their sewer, they pay for the repair, if it’s in your drain, you do.
There are other arrangements but this is by far the most common.
The chance of you successfully challenging such a law, which was probably the rule when your drain was installed, is insignificant.
Now, if you can prove that the municipality damaged your drain, through negligently conducted roadworks, say, you will have to pay the cost.
